# Web app bad format in google app engine

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I created a PHP web app which runs fine in localhost, but it is incorrectly formatted when I run it through GAE development server.

Do you have any idea why?

Correct format:

[image: Correct format]
Incorrect format:

[image]

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
    - url: /.*
      script: index.php
```

Comment: css missing? can you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: Yes! there's some errors about the CSS and JS, I'll try to fix them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify handlers for your static files so that they get uploaded with your deployed app:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
# Catch all handler for any other requests:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

[Read more about using the `static_dir` or `static_files` options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_static_dir).